# Meaning of "icing being this work" and "was done in whiff"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idiom-meaning

One of my colleagues is a very hard worker, he made software that was required by his counterparts, he got a very awesome response from the other side.

But our manager wrote the following statement in his email:

> About Sam, yes indeed I agree fully, and icing being this work done was done in whiff

I understood that this is a positive response for him, but I didn't understand the words like *icing being this work* and *was done in whiff*.

Comment: Neither part of this conveys anything at all to me. Having read Mick's answer, I can see that might be the intent; but as far as I'm concerned this is not English, it's gibberish.

Comment: This looks like the results of really bad auto-correct or speech-to-text software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Icing" probably means "the icing on the cake", and "done in a whiff" probably means "done very quickly", although the usual idiom is "done in a jiffy" [BrE].

> **the icing on the cake**  ​
>
> something that makes a good situation even better:
>
> - I was just content to see my daughter in such a stable relationship but a grandchild, that really was the icing on the cake.
>
> **jiffy** noun
> ​
> a very short time:
>
> - I'll be with you in a jiffy.
> - I've just got to fetch some books from upstairs - I won't be a jiffy (= I'll be very quick).

Cambridge Dictionary